# facebook og:image content show blank in debugger when using php to echo the image URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

facebook OG fetch image from echoed URL, is this possible?

since I included a php file that will echo the image URL but when I check in Sharing debugger the content is empty

`<meta property="og:image" content="" />`
[image]

**my meta tag** **:**

`<meta property="og:image" content ="<?php include "meta_gambar.php"?>">`

I just tried putting a direct URL image to the `og:image content` and it works

[image]

but including a php file that will echo the URL still results in blank

**and the php file :**

```
<?php
 $module=$_GET['module'];
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 if($module=='detailproduk'){
   //prepare query
   $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT gambar FROM produk WHERE id_produk=?");
    if($stmt===false){
       die("Prepare error" . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
    }
    //Bind parameters
    $bp=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i",$id);
     if($bp===false){
        die("Binding error" . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
     //Execute query
     $bp=mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     if($bp===false){
         die("Execute error" . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
     }
     //bind result
     $bp=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$gambar);
      if($bp===false){
          die("Result bind error" . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
      }
     //Fetch
      $bp=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
       if($bp===false){
           die("Fetching error" .htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
      }
    $image = "http://images.rajafotocopy.com/foto_produk/$gambar";
   }else{
      $image = "http://images.rajafotocopy.com/raja.png";
 }
   echo"$image";
?>
```

Additionally I got this error

> Object Missing a Required Value, a required property 'og:image:url' of type 'url' was not provided.

obviously because the OG does not fetch the echoed URL

**I ran the php file and it returns an echoed URL fine**. so it should be echoed into `og:image content` too

**html meta tags**

```
<title> <?php include "dina_titel.php"; ?></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<meta property="og:description" content=" <?php include "dina_meta1.php"; ?>">
<meta name="webcrawlers" content="all">
<meta name="rating" content="general">
<meta name="spiders" content="all">
<meta property="og:image" content ="<?php include 'meta_gambar.php'?>">
```

**what facebook scraper sees**

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title> rajafotocopy sewa jual mesin fotocopy</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <meta property="og:description" content=" PT.Buana Citra Abadi Sewa mesin fotocopy &amp; Jual Mesin Fotocopy new/rekondisi murah import hub : [phone number]">
 <meta name="webcrawlers" content="all">
 <meta name="rating" content="general">
 <meta name="spiders" content="all">
 <meta property="og:image" content="">
```

notice that with `og:description`, the content is filled with echoed string

but `og:image` content is blank

Comment: why can't it get an echoed URL??

Comment: please help me. I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Using include in a position like this is really bad style. You should rather embed the script further at the top, together with the rest of your data processing logic, and have it store the result in a variable, so that you can output it in the relevant place later on when you generate the HTML output. As for the problem why your script doesn’t return the expected value - well you’ll need to do some _debugging_ ...